# How to change a FileStream to a string?

Tags: c#, filestream

In have the following code how can I change the stream to taking in a string variable?

```
        // open dictionary file
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(dictionaryPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8);

        // read line by line
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
        {
            string tempLine = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (tempLine.Length > 0)
            {
                // check for section flag
                switch (tempLine)
                {
                    case "[Copyright]" :
                    case "[Try]" : 
                    case "[Replace]" : 
                    case "[Prefix]" :

                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
```

Comment: First, what have you tried, and do you mean that you want to stream a string...this already is a stream essentially....

Comment: Just guessing, are you looking to replace the FileStream with an existing string then read from that string?

Comment: @DanPichelman: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need to call `ReadLine()` - in this case you can change the type of `sr` to `TextReader`.

You can then replace your `StreamReader` with a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader.aspx) and pass in the string you want to use:

```
TextReader sr = new StringReader(inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) ? It creates a stream that read the content of a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string and you want to read from it like it was a stream:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(theString);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion.. "stay away of streams, if you can"

In this case, you can

1) Read All File in a string variable;

2) Split it in array of strings at the line-end chars (`\r\n`)

3) Do a simple `foreach` cycle and put your switch statement inside it

Little Example:

```
string dictionaryPath = @"C:\MyFile.ext";

string dictionaryContent = string.empty;

try // intercept file not exists, protected, etc..
{
    dictionaryContent = File.ReadAllText(dictionaryPath);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // write error in log, or prompt it to user
    return; // exit from method
}

string[] dictionary = dictionaryContent.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (string entry in dictionary)
{
    switch (entry)
    {
        case "[Copyright]":
            break;

        case "[Try]":
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: it seems 'File.ReadAllText', 'File.ReadLines', ... locks the files for whole duration of read which makes it unavailable to other readers. in my server I was getting File is locked error very frequently and sessions would fail, changing it to stream with FileShare.Read fixed the issue. so I guess which method is better depends on the situation.